# Magento 2: Cannot override translation csv

Tags: magento2, csv, localisation

I need to change the default text of the review submitted into another one.
Right now, I have the default text which is "You submitted your review for moderdation" and I want it to change it in "Thanks, you submitted your review".

I tried to do it in the "standard" way, so I created the en_US.csv in the folder:

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv
```

I did a deploy, cleaned cache, flushed cache, but nothing. The string is not translated.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below line in your csv file here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/en_US.csv

```
"You submitted your review for moderation.","Thanks, you submitted your review."
```

**If any spell mistake is there in your text then your translation will not work.**

In your case, Can you please check spelling of `moderation` ? You've added `moderdation` that may be causing this issue.

Hope this solution will work for you!

Comment: That's exactly what I've done, but it didn't work :/

Comment: Can you please check in your pub/static directory's i18n folder?

is there any en_US.csv file available ?

Comment: You can remove **pub/static/frontend/*** directory and then clear cache and flush cache. that will work then.

Comment: Thank you man. It worked!

Comment: You're welcome 